# simple iframe in javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I currently have this piece of code on my website:

```
<iframe src="https://www.externalnweb.com/otherdomain/external.html" 
height="0" width="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

And I want to do the same, but using javascript.

I would like javascript to call an HTML that is on another external site (another domain)

I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function prepareFrame() {
 var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://www.externweb.com/othersite/externahtml.html");
    ifrm.style.width = "0px";
    ifrm.style.height = "0px";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea or suggestion?
Thank you very much!

Comment: when does said function run?

Comment: @Kevin B It has no call parameters and no special calls are needed. It is called whenever you visit the website.It is a classic iframe in a classic and static html web page.

Comment: have you tryed on body set property `onload="prepareframe();"`

Comment: @sugusrojo How? None of the code you've presented would cause that function to be ran?

Comment: look at this: 
    https://codepen.io/alvaro-alves/pen/ZjwWBB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
ifrm.setAttribute('id', 'ifrm'); // assign an id

//document.body.appendChild(ifrm); // to place at end of document

// to place before another page element
var el = document.getElementById('marker');
el.parentNode.insertBefore(ifrm, el);

// assign url
ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'demo.html');
```

The insertBefore method was used for this example while the appendChild alternative is shown in code comments.

For more information, go to https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/dyn-gen/

Comment: Thanks! Works perfects!

Answer (score -1):

i just modified a little bit your code:
HTML:

```
<html>
    <body onload="prepareFrame();">

    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function prepareFrame() {
   var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
   ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://codepen.io");
   ifrm.style.width = "1000px";
   ifrm.style.height = "1000px";
   document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

you can check this codepen: https://codepen.io/alvaro-alves/pen/ZjwWBB